How can I update certain rows based on a criteria?
I am struggling with implementing two 'flag' columns to show whether an applicant has been through a process called 'Clearing' or not, and whether that applicant had a prior standard application to University - and then went through Clearing. These two flags are called 'In Clearing?' and 'Prior standard application?'
I can tell whether an applicant has been through Clearing based on two columns in two tables: 'Decision Desc' = 'UA Clearing' (Table 'Sequence'), and their 'Choice Number' = 7 (Table 'Final'). If these conditions were true, they would have a 'Yes' in the 'In Clearing?' column.
I can tell whether an Clearing applicant also had a prior standard application because they will have another row with 'Choice Number' = 1-5, on top of the existing 'UA Clearing' and 'Choice Number' = 7 in another row. If these conditions were true, they would have a 'Yes' in the 'Prior standard application?' column.
Each applicant/row has the unique identifier of 'ID'. The only applicants that should be effected by this process are ones with 'Choice Number' 7.
To summarise:
'In Clearing?' = 'Yes' if Decision Desc = 'UA Clearing' and 'Choice Number' = 7.
'Prior standard application?' = 'Yes' if 'In Clearing' = 'Yes' and 'Choice Number' = 1-5.
Only add to 'Yes' to rows with 'Choice Number' = 7.
The problem I cannot solve: making it so the only rows that get affected by this are ones with 'Choice Number' 7.
For example, this is what I am aiming for:



ID
Course Code
Decision Desc
Choice Number
In Clearing?
Prior standard application?




U15
A1
UA Clearing
1
NULL
NULL


U15
C7
UA Clearing
7
Yes
Yes


U48
R9
UA Clearing
2
NULL
NULL


U53
G1
UA Clearing
7
Yes
NULL



As you can see, U15 has 'Yes' in both because it has one row with 'Decision Desc' = 'UA Clearing' and 'Choice Number' = 7, and another row with Choice Number '1-5'. HOWEVER, 'In Clearing?' and 'Prior standard application?' should only have 'Yes' on the row that has Choice Number '7'.
This is the code I've tried:
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS SA_ConfirmationAndClearing_CurrentYearDecisionSequence_Clearing;

-- Copy data of BOXI source into new file for Clearing content
SELECT *
INTO SA_ConfirmationAndClearing_CurrentYearDecisionSequence_Clearing
FROM SA_ConfirmationAndClearing_CurrentYearDecisionSequence

-- Add Flag columns to Sequence_Clearing show whether an applicant is in Clearing or not, and if they have a standard application prior to clearing.
-- Done repeatedly because this table is dropped in this script
ALTER TABLE SA_ConfirmationAndClearing_CurrentYearDecisionSequence_Clearing 
ADD [In Clearing?] varchar(255),
    [Prior standard application?] varchar (255)

-- Create temporary table to track UCAS IDs with different application scenarios
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #UCAS_ID_to_Choice_Number;

-- Classify UCAS IDs based on their choice numbers and decision desc
SELECT 
    Final.[UCAS Id],
    CASE
        WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Final.[Choice Number] = '7' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) > 0
             AND COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Final.[Choice Number] IN ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5') THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) > 0 THEN '1-5 and 7 - Both'
        WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Final.[Choice Number] = '7' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) > 0 THEN 'Only 7 - Clearing'
        ELSE '1-5 - Nulls'
    END as [Choice Number Type]
INTO #UCAS_ID_to_Choice_Number
FROM [REP_ConfirmationAndClearing_Final] as Final
JOIN SA_ConfirmationAndClearing_CurrentYearDecisionSequence_Clearing as Sequence
    ON Final.[UCAS Id] = Sequence.[UCAS Id]
WHERE Sequence.[Decision Desc] = 'UA Clearing'
GROUP BY Final.[UCAS Id];

-- Update the _Clearing table based on the temp table
UPDATE Sequence
SET
    [In Clearing?] = CASE
                        WHEN UCASTempTable.[Choice Number Type] IN ('Only 7 - Clearing', '1-5 and 7 - Both') THEN 'Yes'
                        ELSE NULL
                     END,
    [Prior standard application?] = CASE
                                        WHEN UCASTempTable.[Choice Number Type] = '1-5 and 7 - Both' THEN 'Yes'
                                        ELSE NULL
                                     END
FROM SA_ConfirmationAndClearing_CurrentYearDecisionSequence_Clearing as Sequence
JOIN #UCAS_ID_to_Choice_Number as UCASTempTable
    ON Sequence.[UCAS Id] = UCASTempTable.[UCAS Id]
WHERE Sequence.[Decision Desc] = 'UA Clearing';

-- Update the Final table
UPDATE Final
SET 
    Final.[In Clearing?] = COALESCE(Clearing.[In Clearing?], NULL),
    Final.[Prior standard application?] = COALESCE(Clearing.[Prior standard application?], NULL)
FROM [REP_ConfirmationAndClearing_Final] AS Final
INNER JOIN [SA_ConfirmationAndClearing_CurrentYearDecisionSequence_Clearing] AS Clearing
ON Final.[UCAS Id] = Clearing.[UCAS Id]
WHERE Clearing.[Decision Desc] = 'UA Clearing';

This script is making the error of adding 'Yes' to the rows with 'Choice Number' = 1-5, when it should be the ones with 'Choice Number' = 7.
Example with error:



ID
Course Code
Decision Desc
Choice Number
In Clearing?
Prior standard application?




U15
A1
UA Clearing
1
Yes
Yes


U15
C7
UA Clearing
7
Yes
Yes



The error here is that both rows have 'Yes' in the 'In Clearing?' and 'Prior standard application?' columns, when it should only be the one with 'Choice Number' 7.

The [Course Code] column is not included in your logic. The [Prior standard application?] calculation matches ID values, but ignores [Course Code]. Was that intended?

I think what you have is way more complicated than it need to be, and can be reduced down to a single SELECT statement.
As I understand your requirements:

[In Clearing?] should be set to 'Yes' only for rows having [Choice Number] = '7'.
[Prior standard application?] should be set to 'Yes' if any other row  with the same ID has [Choice Number] IN ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5') but you want to limit this to rows having [Choice Number] = '7'.

The first can be calculated with a simple CASE expression, since the condition only involves data on the same row.
The second can be accomplished using a combination of a CASE expression, a window function, and a technique known as conditional aggregation.
SELECT
    *,
    CASE WHEN [Choice Number] = '7'
        THEN 'Yes'
        END AS [In Clearing?],
    CASE WHEN [Choice Number] = '7'
        AND COUNT(CASE WHEN [Choice Number] IN ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5') THEN 1 END)
                OVER(PARTITION BY ID) > 0
        THEN 'Yes'
        END AS [Prior standard application?]
FROM SA_ConfirmationAndClearing_CurrentYearDecisionSequence
WHERE [Decision Desc] = 'UA Clearing';

A  window function like COUNT(...) OVER(...) allows us to sample data from other rows in the result. The OVER(PARTITION BY ID) limits the sampling scope to rows having the same ID value. (No GROUP BY is needed.) By placing a CASE expression inside the COUNT(...), we limit the count to those rows that satisfy a condition. The THEN 1 cases are counted, while the implicit ELSE NULL cases are not. This technique is commonly called conditional aggregation. A non-zero count indicates that some row in the partition satisfies the condition.
Since you only want the [Prior standard application?] to be set on rows having [Choice Number] = '7', we include an AND condition to that effect, and wrap everything up in another CASE expression yielding 'Yes' or NULL.
Sample results:



ID
Course Code
Decision Desc
Choice Number
In Clearing?
Prior standard application?




U15
A1
UA Clearing
1
null
null


U15
C7
UA Clearing
7
Yes
Yes


U48
R9
UA Clearing
2
null
null


U53
G1
UA Clearing
7
Yes
null



See this db<>fiddle for a demo.
